Scraping Collapsible Table in R
I am using R Selenium to collect data from a collapsible table. I have been successful in scraping the main table, but I would also like to collect the sub-table data for each company.
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(netstat)
library(data.table)

remote_driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "126.0.6478.182", verbose = F, port = free_port())
remDr <- remote_driver$client
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://graphics.axios.com/2019-02-11-harris-polls/index.html?initialWidth=787&amp;childId=av-2019-02-11-harris-polls-N8S34&amp;parentTitle=The%20Axios%20Harris%20Poll%20100%20reputation%20rankings&amp;parentUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.axios.com%2F2019%2F03%2F06%2Faxios-harris-poll-corporate-reputations")
expand_table <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/span')
expand_table$clickElement()

data_table <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '/html/body/div/div[2]/table')
data_table_html <- data_table$getPageSource()
page <- read_html(data_table_html %>% unlist())
  
  df <- html_table(page)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
I think in this case, I would need to create a loop that systematically expands each subtable and extract the html table for that data. I have tried to identify the '+' elements using the findElements but am getting an error.
sub_tables <- remDr$findElements(using = 'class name', 'annotation expand')

Selenium message:Compound class names not permitted

Unless {RSelenium} is a strict requirement here, extracting data from Javascript source seems more straightforward approach in this case.
If you check network tab of your browser while loading that page and fiddling with tables, you can identify the actual data source through Serach (CTRL+f in Chrome for Windows, for example search for "Wegmans", the 1st company). Only meaningful match is a minified js script, all the details for all companies are embedded right there.
Let's start by extracting that script url from page source, we can then fetch the script with httr2 and work out a regular expression that would return only the part where data object is created. At this point we have a piece of valid Javascript. We can evaluate it in V8 js engine and turn resulting object into a valid JSON string, which happens to parse quite nicely into semi-flat frame:
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(httr2)
library(V8)
#> Using V8 engine 11.8.172.13
url_ <- "https://graphics.axios.com/2019-02-11-harris-polls/index.html"

# get link to javascript
js_attr_src <- 
  read_html(url_) |> 
  html_element("script") |> 
  html_attr("src")
js_attr_src
#> [1] "js/app.b1e00630c4751b7ccae0.min.js?b1e00630c4751b7ccae0"

# build full script src url & fetch it as text  
js_content_str <- 
  str_replace(url_, "index.html$", js_attr_src) |> 
  request() |> 
  req_perform() |> 
  resp_body_string()

# dataset is embedded in the minified js script,
# start of the dataset object:
# r.exports=[{"2019_rank":1,"2019_rq":83,industry:"Groceries",history:[...],dimensions:{AFFINITY:{score:81.9,rank:5},...},"2018_rank":2,"2018_rq":82.8,change:-1,company:"Wegmans"} 

# end of the dataset object:
# ,TRAJECTORY:{score:51,rank:99}},change:null,company:"U.S. Government"}]}
  
# extract a part that would match with "\[\{.*?\}\]" and is between 
# "r\.exports=" and  "\}"  (non-inclusive, positive lookbehind & lookahead)
js <- str_extract(js_content_str, "(?<=r\\.exports=)\\[\\{.*?\\}\\](?=\\})") 
# let's check if start and end of the extracted js snippet are what we expected
str_trunc(js, 80, side = "right")
#> [1] "[{\"2019_rank\":1,\"2019_rq\":83,industry:\"Groceries\",history:[{year:\"2009\",rank:..."
str_trunc(js, 80, side = "left")
#> [1] "...nk:99},TRAJECTORY:{score:51,rank:99}},change:null,company:\"U.S. Government\"}]"

# let's evaluate it with V8 javascript engine and turn resulting object into pretty-printed 
# JSON string
ctx <- v8()
json_str <- ctx$eval(str_glue("JSON.stringify({js}, null, 2)")) 

str_trunc(json_str, 80, side = "right") |> str_view()
#> [1] │ [
#>     │   {
#>     │     "2019_rank": 1,
#>     │     "2019_rq": 83,
#>     │     "industry": "Groceries",
#>     │    ...
str_trunc(json_str, 80, side = "left")  |> str_view()
#> [1] │ ... 99
#>     │       }
#>     │     },
#>     │     "change": null,
#>     │     "company": "U.S. Government"
#>     │   }
#>     │ ]

# parse json, return almost flat tibble (history is nested) 
flat_tbl <- 
  jsonlite::fromJSON(json_str, flatten = TRUE) |> 
  as_tibble()

Resulting frame:
flat_tbl
#> # A tibble: 100 × 26
#>    `2019_rank` `2019_rq` industry   history `2018_rank` `2018_rq` change company
#>          <int>     <dbl> <chr>      <list>        <int>     <dbl>  <int> <chr>  
#>  1           1      83   Groceries  <df>              2      82.8     -1 Wegmans
#>  2           2      82.3 Other      <df>              1      83.2      1 Amazon 
#>  3           3      81.4 Apparel    <df>              9      80.4     -6 Patago…
#>  4           4      80.7 Apparel    <df>             15      79.8    -11 L.L. B…
#>  5           5      80.4 Other      <df>              5      81.5      0 Walt D…
#>  6           6      80.3 Groceries  <df>              8      80.8     -2 Publix 
#>  7           7      80   Technology <df>             35      77.6    -28 Samsung
#>  8           8      79.8 Consumer … <df>             20      79.3    -12 Procte…
#>  9           9      79.7 Technology <df>             11      80.4     -2 Micros…
#> 10          10      79.4 Technology <df>             31      78.1    -21 Sony   
#> # ℹ 90 more rows
#> # ℹ 18 more variables: dimensions.AFFINITY.score <dbl>,
#> #   dimensions.AFFINITY.rank <int>, dimensions.ETHICS.score <dbl>,
#> #   dimensions.ETHICS.rank <int>, dimensions.GROWTH.score <dbl>,
#> #   dimensions.GROWTH.rank <int>, `dimensions.P&S.score` <dbl>,
#> #   `dimensions.P&S.rank` <int>, dimensions.CITIZENSHIP.score <dbl>,
#> #   dimensions.CITIZENSHIP.rank <int>, dimensions.VISION.score <dbl>, …
glimpse(flat_tbl)
#> Rows: 100
#> Columns: 26
#> $ `2019_rank`                  <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13…
#> $ `2019_rq`                    <dbl> 83.0, 82.3, 81.4, 80.7, 80.4, 80.3, 80.0,…
#> $ industry                     <chr> "Groceries", "Other", "Apparel", "Apparel…
#> $ history                      <list> [<data.frame[11 x 3]>], [<data.frame[11 …
#> $ `2018_rank`                  <int> 2, 1, 9, 15, 5, 8, 35, 20, 11, 31, 7, 26,…
#> $ `2018_rq`                    <dbl> 82.8, 83.2, 80.4, 79.8, 81.5, 80.8, 77.6,…
#> $ change                       <int> -1, 1, -6, -11, 0, -2, -28, -12, -2, -21,…
#> $ company                      <chr> "Wegmans", "Amazon", "Patagonia", "L.L. B…
#> $ dimensions.AFFINITY.score    <dbl> 81.9, 82.2, 81.0, 81.6, 78.8, 80.4, 79.4,…
#> $ dimensions.AFFINITY.rank     <int> 5, 4, 8, 7, 21, 11, 17, 13, 19, 20, 1, 2,…
#> $ dimensions.ETHICS.score      <dbl> 84.4, 79.3, 82.3, 82.5, 80.1, 82.6, 78.5,…
#> $ dimensions.ETHICS.rank       <int> 1, 16, 4, 3, 11, 2, 21, 23, 24, 13, 19, 9…
#> $ dimensions.GROWTH.score      <dbl> 85.2, 87.8, 82.1, 80.0, 82.7, 82.8, 83.6,…
#> $ dimensions.GROWTH.rank       <int> 2, 1, 10, 22, 6, 5, 3, 11, 7, 16, 12, 23,…
#> $ `dimensions.P&S.score`       <dbl> 85.2, 85.0, 84.5, 82.3, 83.4, 82.4, 84.0,…
#> $ `dimensions.P&S.rank`        <int> 1, 2, 3, 11, 7, 10, 4, 6, 5, 9, 38, 13, 3…
#> $ dimensions.CITIZENSHIP.score <dbl> 81.2, 76.6, 79.2, 78.8, 75.5, 78.0, 73.9,…
#> $ dimensions.CITIZENSHIP.rank  <int> 1, 6, 2, 3, 9, 5, 20, 7, 18, 26, 21, 11, …
#> $ dimensions.VISION.score      <dbl> 85.9, 86.8, 83.8, 81.4, 83.6, 82.6, 81.3,…
#> $ dimensions.VISION.rank       <int> 2, 1, 3, 13, 4, 8, 14, 9, 6, 30, 15, 40, …
#> $ dimensions.CULTURE.score     <dbl> 84.8, 80.6, 81.5, 81.6, 80.6, 80.7, 78.4,…
#> $ dimensions.CULTURE.rank      <int> 1, 12, 5, 4, 13, 11, 20, 18, 14, 6, 2, 30…
#> $ dimensions.CHARACTER.score   <dbl> 82.3, 78.2, 79.9, 80.7, 77.7, 79.6, 77.0,…
#> $ dimensions.CHARACTER.rank    <int> 1, 8, 3, 2, 10, 4, 14, 11, 18, 16, 7, 17,…
#> $ dimensions.TRAJECTORY.score  <dbl> 84.9, 85.8, 83.6, 81.2, 83.1, 82.2, 83.0,…
#> $ dimensions.TRAJECTORY.rank   <int> 2, 1, 3, 11, 5, 8, 6, 7, 4, 10, 26, 16, 1…

Created on 2024-07-24 with reprex v2.1.0
